# select only the first letters of a column and make the check

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column called dates in sqlite3 as follows:

```
20/20/2000 12:34:44 PM
21/20/2000 09:11:32 AM
22/20/2000 18:14:04 PM
```

All I'm trying to do is create a select in which will fetch only 10 existing letters in this column, I'm using substr, my syntax is as follows:

```
Select * from currier WHERE substr(dates, 1, 9) = '20/20/2000'
```

But this syntax don't run why?

Comment: Well, you could do `substr(dates, 1, 10) = '20/20/2000'`, if you want 10 characters.  Just an idea.

Comment: Do you get any errors? or what mean "don't run"?

Comment: Hey I put substr(dates, 1, 10) and works, thanks